# New Messages LinkedIn group

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the new messages posted in a subscribed linkedIn group for a member via the API.

As per 
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#membergroups
closest I would get is retrieve discussions posts based on a timestamp filter

Is there any resource or another place in the API docs where this's explained ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be supported via the API as it's not part of their Open Developer program

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to retrieve the comments and iterate through them, filtering posts against the user(s) that you are checking for. This would be 'API intensive', in that you'd need to make repeated calls to the Groups API to get all of the group posts - the [throttle limits](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits) restrict pulling group posts to 1000/user per day.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I shall look into that.